# google app engine sdk: read mp3 files and save to local blobstore

Tags: google-app-engine, blobstore

In Google App Engine SDK, I would like to read thousands of audio files and save them to the local blobstore. After this is done, I'd upload the whole blobstore to the cloud.

Creating an HTML form for uploading audio files is not acceptable because there are thousands of files and uploading one by one is impossible.

The followings are my hypothetical solution:

The model:

```
class MP3(ndb.Model):
    video = StringProperty()
    ...
```

The python program that runs locally:

```
mp3 = MP3()
file = open(fn)     # 'fn': file name of an mp3 file
save_to_blobstore(file)
mp3.video = blobstore_key()
mp3.put()
```

In the above, how do I implement `save_to_blobstore()` and `blobstore_key()`?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I understand your question. App Engine runs on Googles cloud infrastructure, so the blobstore is already in the cloud. Maybe you mean Google Cloud Storage?

If your aim is to get your audio files into Google Cloud Storage, then you do not need to use App Engine at all - just use [gsutil](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil) to [copy the files](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/cp).

If you do want to use App Engine, you can also use an HTML form for uploading files. By implementing the `multiple` attribute, you can select as many files as you like. You can then use javascript and ajax to upload the data using a `FormData` object. [Here's an example using drag and drop.](http://html5doctor.com/drag-and-drop-to-server/)

Comment: Hi Gwyn, you know perfectly what I am trying to do. We are developing an App Engine application, and we used to use an html form to upload multimedia file and store it in the blobstore. However, if there are thousands of files, this would not be a good idea. So we thought it might be better to populate the blobstore locally, and then upload the blobstore (Too bad, App Engine doesn't allow creating files). I'll try your suggestions. Thanks a lot.